# It is possible to copy firebase document and all it sub collection to another document using angular

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

Hello all,
As we see an example from the picture I would like to copy all the documents (and its data) containing in collection('planaprendizaje').

For example take the data from document 1 and put on document 10. Choosing if I want planaprendizaje or another sub collection.

I am using angular to connect to firebase in order to try get the data.

Comment: That's definitely possible, but there's no single API call that does this, so you'll have to write the code for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is my solution but using callable cloud functions. You can play with source and dest params.

```js
const functions = require( 'firebase-functions' );
const admin = require( 'firebase-admin' );

const copyDoc = async ( source, dest ) => {
  const docRef = admin.firestore().doc( source );

  const docData = await docRef
    .get()
    .then( ( doc ) => doc.exists && doc.data() )
    .catch( ( error ) => {
      console.error( 'Error reading document', `${source}`, error.message );
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError( 'not-found', 'Copying document was not read' );
    } );

  if ( docData ) {
    await admin
      .firestore()
      .doc( dest )
      .set( docData )
      .catch( ( error ) => {
        console.error( 'Error creating document', `${dest}`, error.message );
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
          'data-loss',
          'Data was not copied properly to the target collection, please try again.',
        );
      } );
  }

  const subcollections = await docRef.listCollections();
  for await ( const subcollectionRef of subcollections ) {
    const subPath = `${source}/${subcollectionRef.id}`
    console.log( 'parsing: ', subPath )
    try {
      const snapshot = await subcollectionRef.get()
      const docs = snapshot.docs;
      for await ( const doc of docs ) {
        console.log( `coping: ${subPath}/${doc.id} -> ${dest}/${subcollectionRef.id}/${doc.id}` )
        await copyDoc( `${subPath}/${doc.id}`, `${dest}/${subcollectionRef.id}/${doc.id}` );
      }
    } catch ( e ) {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'data-loss',
        `${e.message} -> ${subPath}, please try again.`,
      )
    }
  }
}

exports.set = functions
  .region( 'europe-west3' )
  .https.onCall( async ( {source_doc, destination_doc}, context ) => {
    if ( !context.auth ) {
      // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError( 'unauthenticated', 'The function must be called while authenticated.' );
    }
    try {
      await copyDoc( source_doc, destination_doc )
      return { result: destination_doc  }
    } catch ( e ) {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError( 'aborted', e.message );
    }
  } );
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I added    :-  
const source = data.source;
const destination = data.destination; // to get the data in (and replaced the placeholders). data needs to be sent as JSON in the body of a POST, if that helps anyone.